# What level would this cursed invisibility ring be best balanced for?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, homebrew, balance, curses

I am planning on running a campaign, and got an idea for a cursed ring of invisibility. Here are the technical (without the fluff) details.

> ## Cursed Ring of Invisibility
>
> Wearing this ring grants the wearer the benefits of the *invisibility* spell, but it also imposes disadvantage on stealth checks against enemies who can hear.

What character level is this the best balanced for?

Comment: @Sdjz I was changing the question to be "what level should I give this to my players so that it doesn't break the game"

Comment: Is the invisibility (and associated stealth penalty) indefinite, as long as the ring is worn? Can the ring be removed without a remove curse spell? Does it require attunement?

Comment: @Justin They would have just have disadvantage against people who can hear

Comment: @mdrichey This is really just a ring that has a side effect, not an actual curse. But, yes, it is indefinite

Comment: So they would have disadvantage overall against people who can't hear (because they are invisible), but advantage against those who can?

Comment: I assume you switched those, @Justin and yes

Comment: "but it also imposes disadvantage on stealth checks against enemies who can hear" Doesn't the advantage from being invisible just cancel this out?  Also, how are you making multiple stealth checks?  One at advantage and one standard and remembering which one applies to which enemies?

Comment: Could you expand a bit on what balanced means to you?  Along what dimensions would you like considered?

Comment: We also need details on the prevalence of magic items in your world and what types your players currently have at their current level.

Comment: Do the drawbacks of the invisibility spell also apply? If you make an attack or cast a spell, does invisibility drop? This is incredibly important for determining rarity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you confirmed in a comment that the invisibility is to be indefinite, that makes the ring you describe very similar to a *ring of invisibility*, with a minor negative effect added. I would change the description to reference the *ring of invisibility*, or perhaps just the Invisible condition, rather than the *invisibility* spell. And it should definitely require attunement.

A *ring of invisibility* is a legendary item (Basic Rules p. 191), which means it is intended for characters of level 17+ (DMG ch. 7). The stealth penalty could change the rarity from legendary to very rare (intended for characters of level 11+), although I can also see arguments for keeping it as legendary. Indefinite invisibility is a very, very powerful effect, and you as a DM would be responsible for determining how and when stealth checks to remain unheard would come into play.